# How does Training work with Warrior Spirit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, class-feature, feats, fighter

The [Training](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/training/) (weapon enchantment) ability says:

> Popular among those who seek to impersonate skilled warriors, a training weapon grants one combat feat to the wielder as long as the weapon is drawn and in hand. The feat is chosen when this special ability is placed on the weapon. That feat cannot be used as a prerequisite for any other feats and functions for the wielder only if she meets its prerequisites. Once chosen, the feat stored in the weapon cannot be changed.

And [Warrior Spirit (su)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Fighter/#Advanced_Weapon_Training), the Fighter's Advanced Weapon Training option, says:

> The fighter can forge a spiritual bond with a weapon that belongs to the associated weapon group, allowing him to unlock the weapon’s potential. Each day, he designates one such weapon and gains a number of points of spiritual energy equal to 1 + his weapon training bonus. While wielding this weapon, he can spend 1 point of spiritual energy to grant the weapon an enhancement bonus equal to his weapon training bonus. Enhancement bonuses gained by this advanced weapon training option stack with those of the weapon, to a maximum of +5. **The fighter can also imbue the weapon with any one weapon special ability with an equivalent enhancement bonus less than or equal to his maximum bonus by reducing the granted enhancement bonus by the amount of the equivalent enhancement bonus.** The item must have an enhancement bonus of at least +1 (from the item itself or from warrior spirit) to gain a weapon special ability. In either case, these bonuses last for 1 minute.

This seems to me like this is an effective way of getting a combat feat of your choice, reminiscent of a [Brawler](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler)'s Martial Flexibility. For the low, low cost of having an already potent Advanced Weapon Training option.

However, it could be that Training's "lock in" means that taking the ability will always be the same feat.

Do I get to choose a feat for Training every time I activate Warrior Spirit, or would I always get the same feat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You get to choose the feat each time you imbue the weapon

When you select the Advanced Weapon training option, this is what happens:

> Instead of selecting an additional fighter weapon group, a fighter can choose an advanced weapon training option for one fighter weapon group that he previously selected with the weapon training class feature.

Here the option is Warrior Spirit (Su). The option text describes what it does when you use it:

> The fighter can also imbue the weapon with any one weapon special ability

There is no text in the option text or in the introduction about the options instructing you to select a special ability when you *pick* the option (and with which you then would be stuck), there is only text instructing you to select an ability when you *use* the option.
So the ability allows you to imbue the weapon with *any* one weapon special ability every time you use it, not with only one specific pre-set weapon special ability.

However, keep in mind that the effect of imbuing the weapon is transient, so this is not as strong as you might think:

> In either case, these bonuses last for 1 minute.

You spend one point of spiritual energy of the pool you have (equal to your 1 + your weapon training bonus: 2 at 5th level, 3 at 9th, 4 at 13th and 5 at 17th) to convert an already existing enhancement bonus into a special ability of the same value. *Training* is a special ability worth +1 enhancement bonus, so you will need a weapon that already has a +1 enhancement bonus naturally, or you need to first imbue it with such a bonus for a point of spiritual energy. Then you convert that +1 bonus into the Training special ability. At the end of the minute, the special ability (and its equivalent enhancement bonus) will end.

There is no mechanism that lets the weapon remember what special ability you chose the last time, when you use this again or care about this. For example, if you had a normal sword and this was a weapon from your main training group bonded for Warrior Spirit, and you were a  14th level fighter, you could spend 2 points to create a +1 enhancement bonus on it and convert it to a combat feat. You then can use that feat for one minute (if you meet its prequisites). When you do this again in the next fight on hour later, you can choose another feat. You even could do this process twice at the same time, as it carries no action cost, and gain two different combat feats from it at the same time, both lasting for a minute.

If you already have a magic weapon with a +1 enhancement bonus, you could use this for up to five fights in the day (depending on your level) by forgoing that enhancement bonus. But just using the option itself, it is quite costly limited in number of uses.

Comment: Okay, clear answer. Thanks. Combat encounters tend to be limited to under a minute and one or two a day, while I got the Gloves of Duelling for +2 Weapon Training bonus. So my circumstances make Warrior Spirit even better than it would ordinarily be.

Comment: Your answer to the OP is correct, but some other things are not. Using a supernatural ability is a standard action unless defined otherwise by the ability’s description. Also, you can't forgo any enhancement bonus the weapon already has, only reduce the enhancement bonus granted by warrior spirit, and only if the total enhancement bonus is at least +1. A weapon can never have a special ability without an enhancement bonus. And you don't need 2 points to to create a +1 enhancement bonus with training. One point will give you both if you have weapon training 2. And it doesn't stack with itself.